# How to hide a content type on the node add page?

Tags: 7, nodes

I need a way to hide a content type on the node add page, or better yet, make two separated node add pages that separate my content types. I'm on Drupal 7 and have four different content types. I would like three of them to be on the default node add page and the fourth to be separate. How would I do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- `admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation` move/delete menu item that you don't want.
- Cleanest way: use roles and permissions. If the user can't create a content type the link will not appear in any menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your first possible way is the one I would use because I still need users to be able to create nodes of my fourth content type. I just need it separated from the other three.

Comment: Ok so just move the menu item in another menu or hide it and create another one this the same menu link (node/add/<your_content_type>)

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Put this in a custom module:

```
function yourcustommodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['node/add/your-content-type'])) {
    $items['node/add/your-content-type']['type'] = MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK;
  }
}
```

Comment: MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK converts the links into tabs. I have used MENU_CALLBACK instead.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

`MENU_CALLBACK`, as suggested in other answers, didn't work for me here. They still appear on the `node/add` page.

This code worked:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['node/add/your-content-type'])) {
    unset($items['node/add/your-content-type']);
  }
}
```

Of course, it assumes you want to disable (not hide) the `node/add` link for that type.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The `node/add` page is provided by the Node module. You might be able to do what you want by disabling the menu item in the Navigation menu, according to this post: http://data.agaric.com/disabling-or-moving-nodeaddcontent-type-links-from-beneath-add-content-navigation-menu-also-removes

It's a bit of a bug, so it might not be a reliable way to do it. Personally, I'd create a custom version of the `node/add` page in a module by copying the existing one and making my specific modifications. Then I would use [`hook_menu_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to make `node/add` go to my version.

You might be able to replace it with a view or panel instead (with Page Manager), but I haven't tried this, and you'd probably lose the automation.

Comment: Thanks! Where is the `node/add` page located in for me to copy? And how would you suggest printing out the different content types?

Comment: It should be in `node.pages.inc`. If you need the other types to show up as you create them and don't have a static list, do it in code.

Comment: Self-follow-up: I don't like my own answer from 4.5 years ago. Use one of the ones above :)

Answer (score 0):

There is now a best solution in contrib (Drupal 7 and modern Drupal) that makes it easy again, providing a separate menu to power a replacement "Add content" page:

https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_add_content

(Glad i found that module as i was about to make the equivalent, since it was my fault it got difficult— as wizonesolutions pointed to, i reported [the bug that disconnected the menu from the page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1009982))